# Visualising results from 'effects' package

Tags: data-visualization, mixed, effects

1. Any ideas on how to control the tick-label size e.g. on the following code i'd like to control the font size of the words 'Male' and 'Female' on the x axis and the units of 'volunteer' on the Y axis.
2. Any ideas on how to plot prediction intervals rather than confidence intervals would also be much appreciated.

### code from here.

```
library(effects);
library(stats);
mod.cowles <- glm(volunteer ~ sex + neuroticism*extraversion, data=Cowles, family=binomial);
eff.cowles <- allEffects(mod.cowles, xlevels=list(neuroticism=0:24, extraversion=seq(0, 24, 6)));
plot(eff.cowles, par.strip.text = list(cex = 1.2), xlab=list(cex=2.8), cex=2.5 #par.settings=list(scales=list(cex=1.4),#doesn't work.
#par.scales=list(cex=1.4),#doesn't work.
#scales=list(cex=1.4),#doesn't work
#pscales=list(cex=1.5)#doesn't work. 
)
```

Comment: I voted off topic as about R rather than stats.  But on 1. try plot(eff.cowles, cex.lab=.4).

Comment: I agree with @PeterEllis ; you could also try writing the author of the package.

Answer (score 0):

On your first question, I think you're looking for

```
plot(eff.cowles, cex.lab=.4)
```

The cex.lab argument is probably what you need.

I don't know an easy way to do prediction intervals rather than confidence intervals, although I'm sure it's possible.